# Dynamically adding usercontrol to placeholder

Tags: c#, user-controls, placeholder

I'm having a brain freeze moment today. I must've done this many times but just can't work it out:
All i'm doing is running the following, but it's not saying releasestable is right.

```
Error   55  The type or namespace name 'releasestable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\tomb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Findnzbs\Findnzbs\latestreleases.aspx.cs    16  11  Findnzbs
```

Heres the code:

```
 releasestable webUserControl = (releasestable)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/releasestable.ascx");
  webUserControl.listWhere = "myWhere";
  phReleases.Controls.Add(webUserControl);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you need to add it on the top of your code

like

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Data;
using Findnzbs.Controls;
```

Comment: It would be tidier if you updated your original answer with all these extra details

Comment: There's no need to paste code into the comments, just edit the Answer, but hey, it's resolved now

Answer (score 0):

is it

```
releasestable webUserControl (releasestable)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/releasestable.ascx");
  webUserControl.listWhere = "myWhere";
```

or

```
releasestable webUserControl= (releasestable)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/releasestable.ascx");
  webUserControl.listWhere = "myWhere";
```

Comment: Sorry it has the = - i'm not sure where it went on my paste

Answer (score 0):

Ok then the solution is add your namespace of the control.
example

if your application name is demoproject, then add

```
using demoproject.Controls;
```

where Controls is the folder were you have control code.

in your case it is Controls. so just copy paste the above line

Comment: Hey - Thanks for the input but i get a : Error 57 'Findnzbs.Controls' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' =